# Mouse acting weird on old PC

Tags: windows-xp, mouse, taskbar, mouse-click

So I have an old desktop computer with Windows XP on it(yes, shame on me--but I don't use it much so), and ive always had a problem on it that I never really took care of since I don't use this PC much. But I would still like to fix that.

This problem occurs with every PC mouse, I tried 2 different wireless mouse and 1 regular mouse with a cord and I was having the same issue. The problem is kinda hard to catch because it seems really random. The problem is that the left click work only from time to time, works in some opened window, and don't work in others.

When I boot up the PC, the left click doesn't work at all; what I have to do I removed batteries from the mouse and replace them and it's going to work good for a little while. And then it will start back to act weird. For example,I have "My documents open"--I'll be able to select and do all normal left click options in the my document folder--but I won't be able to click in the task bar, desktop and google chrome, it just doesn't do anything. Sometimes clicking icons on the desktop work, and then clicking in google chrome(address bar, menu, etc)and the taskbar won't work. I have to open the task manager with `CTRL-ALT-DELETE` and close it(or remove and put back batteries in the mouse) to be able to "change" the issue and make me able to click in chrome(but then won't be able to click taskbar, desktop...).

I tried replacing the batteries and 3 different mouse and still did not fix it. I've had this problem for a while on this PC. Always had Kaspersky IS on it and up to date. Any ideas?

Comment: There is one thing sure: the batteries have nothing to do with this issue. A simple unplug/plug in should have the same effect. Is that possible that applications just load a bit slow, and while You were changing the battery it just loads and gets ready to work? Was this issue always present or it just started to work like this?

Comment: Well the main mouse I use with this one PC is an old microsoft wireless mouse that came with a wireless keyboard;they use the same USB dongle ,but only the mouse act weird,the keyboard works correctly.I dont think its applications being slow because if it was a speed issue,the problem would fix by itself(once its loaded) at on point.However in my case the problems just stays forever.My PC is a 2008 PC , core 2 duo 3.5Ghz with 3-4GB RAM so I dont think its a performance issue considering its also just running Windows XP @Divin3

Comment: and Ive had this issue for at least about 2-3 years @Divin3

Comment: First, plug your USB into other ports and see if the problem remains. If Yes, go to device manager, uninstall the mouse, unplug it and plug it back in. After that, also from device manager, try to update the driver.

Comment: Ok heres what I tried: I tried all the USB ports with the old wireless mouse and another one; I uninstalled and reinstalled several times the mouse/keyboard driver;Tried to update the driver,but they said its already up to date(intellipoint 8.2).Sometimes it was fixing the problem for a few minutes but in google chrome when I left click a tab(not the "X")it closes it.However I dont have any problems in firefox(?).Also tried to resync mouse several times with the dongle.Sometimes it fix it for a few mins,sometimes it makes it worse.This is very strange @Divin3

Comment: Since You have tried multiple mouses and got the same result, we can be sure, that it is not caused by the mouse. Have You tried a different keyboard as well? Saw similar things when a key was stuck. Try turning off your keyboard and check if the problem appears again. We also can not say for sure that this is not a virus. Anti-virus software does not give 100% protection. You should also scan your pc with a few anti malware software.

Comment: EDIT: I finally found a way to fix it!! What I did: Started normally the PC,once fully ready.unplugged USB receiver of the old mouse/keyboard.Then plugged in the USB receiver of a newer mouse.Rebooted computer.After the reboot,the mouse was working perfectly fine! I just plugged back in the old keyboard USB receiver to be able to use the keyboard and everything is fine now!!I guess its a problem between the old USB receiver and the old mouse?Not communicating properly?Because im using a newer mouse using a separate USB receiver than the keyboard

Comment: For information, the old mouse that seemed to be faulty was Microsoft wireless laser mouse 6000 v2.0.However,the keyboard that came with this mouse(microsoft wireless keyboard 6000 v3.0) still works perfectly fine.Right now,im using the Microsoft wireless mouse 2000 with Microsoft wireless keyboard 6000 v3.0 and its works perfectly fine.